# OSL Volume in 2.79

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, osl

I'm learning to work with OSL but it seems something has changed between Blender 2.79 and previous versions regarding OSL Volumes...

```
shader node_volume(output closure color Volume = 0) {   Volume = henyey_greenstein(0.0); }
```

This very simple osl volume shader does not work in blender 2.79 but it's working perfectly in 2.78.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: Seems that was a bug. Reported and corrected. https://developer.blender.org/T53048

Comment: As mentioned above it is a bug. it will be part of blender 2.79a. Hopeful it will be released the upcoming weeks. Today we expect that the official test releases will be build.